# How to pass parameter to RDLC report

Tags: rdlc

I am new to reports creation in ASP.net (Local Report). I have used rdlc file to create my report. Objective is, On clicking of the reservation button in a aspx page, the data has to be stored in db and page should open a popup window to show the report (saved details) to the user.

I have created a rdlc file and created/added a parameter too.

my Aspx page:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"
        ZoomMode="PageWidth" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" ProcessingMode="Local"
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" PageCountMode="Actual" Width="750px" Height="500px">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports.rdlc" EnableExternalImages="true"
            EnableHyperlinks="true">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetPaymentVoucherDetailsByWSId"
        TypeName="Controllers.ReservatoionController">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Controller.cs

Created a public method that accepts the Primary key of the record and return the object to the report.

**Query:**

1. How do I pass the primary key from main page to Controller class to get the result?
2. how to set the primary key value dynamically to report?

Comment: Hi bluemoon, here you can find an article that explains how to pass parameters to a report http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.ch/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html

Answer (score -1):

Check Below Link It shows a demo for pass parameter value

www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko1Uejtdi1g

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link

Comment: video is not available